# Back application page, from uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, google-plus

I call  this :

```
    NSString *authLink = @"https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:authLink];
```

[vkWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

after I sent the text,  UIWebView loaded my google+ wall. How hide webview and back to my app?

Comment: how do you display the `UIWebView`? when do you want to get back to you app? after the data has been displayed in the web view? after the user does some action?

Comment: if ([[URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"https://plus.google.com/"]) {
        [super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    }

call this in 

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWbView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the url that the UIWebView is trying to load by using the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate metod.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate for details.

When you get the URL for the google+ wall, just hide / stop the UIWebView